# Simulink Warning; ssSetSolverNeedsReset on the Ground block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink simulation that was made in Matlab r2012b which I'm trying to run in r2016a from an m-file script.  When I run the script, it gives the following warning:

> Warning: Simulink detected that S-function 'Motors_Opt/Machine Model/Rigid Body Dynamics/Ground/_mech_engine/Block#1' changed the value of one or more elements of its continuous state vector without resetting the ODE solver at time 0.0.  Continuous states should only be changed in a major time step and the S-function should request a solver reset using 'ssSetSolverNeedsReset' macro. Changing states without resetting the solver can lead to unexpected results, especially in accelerated simulation modes. Use 'ssSetSkipContStatesConsistencyCheck(S,1)' in mdlInitializeSizes method to disable this check once you have fixed your S-function.

The block the warning is linking to is the `Ground` block (from the Simscape library in Multibody/1-D Generation/Bodies) that I have linked to my `Machine Environment` block.  Am I creating the ground wrong?  How am I supposed to reinitialize the solver in a built-in S-function?

Comment: You can reset solver using the function ssSetSolverNeedsReset mentioned in the error message. There is also an example for this at https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/sssetsolverneedsreset.html

Comment: @Navan I might be misunderstanding, but isn't that example for a user-created S-function, for which the user has the source?  The block that's flagging the warning is not a user-created block, it is one of the built-in blocks from the Simscape library.  I editted the question to be more specific.

Comment: Have you [updated](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/model-upgrades.html) your model to use newer blocks?

Comment: I tried taking the offending block out and replacing it, but it didn't do anything.  Or did you mean completely rewriting the simulation?  That would be pretty cumbersome...

Comment: There are semi-automatic tools available for upgrading a model - such as the Model Advisor (linked in my previous comment) and an older function called `slupdate`.

Comment: If Model Advisor has an option to check for this warning, I'm not finding it in the list, nor am I seeing this warning in the report it gives

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily expect there to be a specific message.  However, if the model is updated (using `slupdate` for instance) then I would expect it to replace any blocks that have new/different features.